# .htaccess RewriteRule is acting strange

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a webpage, which url looks like this:

http://www.mydomain.com/folder/index.php?title=The_title

The only problem is that I want it to look like one of these:

http://www.mydomain.com/folder/The_title

http://www.mydomain.com/folder/The_title.php

I have searched most of a lot and found one solution, which "works":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /folder/index.php?title=$1 [L]
```

It does what it should, except the ending has to be ".html" (or ".kl", if you like). This solution won't accept ".php", which gives me a "500 Internal Server Error". Same thing happens if I try it without the extension.

**EDIT:**
Forgot to mention that the .htaccess file lies in the folder and not the root.

Comment: Nope. Still not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since I couldn't get it to work properly I took the challange and started reading about mod_rewrite, which led to the solution:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?title=$1 [L]
```

If anyone else run into troubles I'll recommend these sites:
[more .htaccess tips and tricks..](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)
[An In Depth Guide to mod_rewrite for Apache](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]*)\.php$ /folder/index.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly no. I've tried almost every combination out there. It simply doesn't work, for some reason.